# Prevent Web page from caching while access through mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, mobile, back-button

I want to prevent my asp.net page from browser caching.
I apply tricks available on internet,So browser stop caching my page and every time request to server for page.

But problem is when i access my site through mobile like blackberry it cache my page and on back button press page access from its cache without ping to server.
I searched a lot but found nothing special.

One solution i found which said that mobile browser only stop caching when https request is made

Is that true or not?

Please help.

Comment: I don't know with it will help, but to avoid the caching in my page, I pass through parameter a ?rand=Math.random(2) , so everytime that the page is called, the number of rand parameter changes, and it will force to pass in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggested method which works with mobile and desktop browser: [Prevent browser caching of web pages in asp.net which works in all browsers (IE/Firefox..)](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1487/prevent-browser-caching-of-web-pages-in-aspnet-which-works-in-all-browsers-ie-firefox/)

Comment: Its only work on firefox and other desktop browser no on mobile default browsers